# Reserve view id range

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

Is it possible to reserve a id range (not a single id) in Android?

If I can reserve a given number of ids under a specific name, then based on my own criteria, I can generate predictable dynamic ids that does not conflict with any other id that android might have assigned to a view.

For eg., if I can reserve a range of 10,000 for my custom view `CustomerView`s (lets assume that a maximum of 10,000 items can be scrolled thru), then based on the reserved id prefix, I can generate a guaranteed unique & predictable id that does not conflict with any other view id in my complete view hierarchy.

This way, my save & restore works irrespective of the other views that might be in my view hierarchy, as save restore is completely tied to view ids.

To make it understand better, lets say I have a custom view named `CustomerView` & I have reserved a total of 100 ids under name `custom_view_id_bag`.

If Android allows this reservation, my customer at index 10 in my collection will always gets an id of `custom_view_id_bag` + `10` irrespective of the number of times the view gets recreated (which is a problem with `View.generateViewId()`) & this id guaranteed to be unique across all views within any view hierarchy my custom view is in.

This way, I have assurance that my `onSaveInstance` & `onRestoreInstance` works properly irrespective of the ids that are assigned else where by Android

The problem with `View.generateViewId()` is that it generates new unique id but non repeatable id. But restore instance only works with repeatable ids.

Also, problem with `ids.xml` is that, you can only reserve a known number of items.

Usecase: You have a dynamic number of views & want to set the same id for the same view irrespective of the number of times the `onDestroyView` & `onCreateView` are invoked.

Comment: You should not add 10,000 views to the view hierarchy (dynamically or not). Why aren't you using `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, it goes without saying that I use some sort recycler if I have large number of items. The core point is about assigning dynamic but predictable id to dynamic number of views (even if they are 1-10)

Comment: Even within recycler view, if you want restore the view state (lets say you have inline edits within recycler views), you need dynamic but predictable ids